# Open HTML file in same tab using python script

Tags: python, html, python-webbrowser

I am trying to open a HTML page using python script. With the following script the file opens in a new browser tab. How should I make it open in the same tab?

```
import webbrowser
import os
import urllib

chrome_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
webbrowser.register('chrome', None,webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(os.path.realpath('image.html'))
```

**EDIT 1:**

I tried adding

```
webbrowser.get('chrome').open(os.path.realpath('image.html'), new=1, autoraise=True)
```

it opens in the same browser but not in the same tab.

Comment: in python docs : https://docs.python.org/2/library/webbrowser.html. I see 
`webbrowser.open(url, new=0, autoraise=True)` Display url using the default browser. If new is 0, the url is opened in the same browser window if possible

Comment: yes, I found that. And it opens in the same browser. But it opens always in a new tab. Is there any way to restrict it from opening in new tab

Comment: one answer comes from firefox :https://support.mozilla.org/fr/questions/970999. Try it with chrome

Comment: Ty @Pain for your effort. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you need to do it through Javascript:

```
RefreshTab = '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">window.location = \'%s\';</script>'
print RefreshTab % 'yourscript.py'
```